# How do I create a stratified sample with 20% from one group and 10% of another

Tags: r, sampling

I have a dataset with the variable "region" I need to take a stratified sample of 20% of the data from the "east" and 10% from the rest of the sample. How would I do that?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 30))`. (`df` is a placeholder for the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse approach. Assuming your data frame is called `df` and your region column is a character one.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Some test data:
df <- data.frame(region = rep(c("east", "west", "north", "south"), 50))

df %>% count(region)

#   region  n
# 1   east 50
# 2  north 50
# 3  south 50
# 4   west 50

set.seed(1)

df_sample <- df %>%
  mutate(east_rest = if_else(region == "east", 1, 2)) %>%
  group_by(east_rest) %>%
  mutate(draw = case_when(region == "east" ~ sample(c(0,1), n(), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)),
                          region != "east" ~ sample(c(0,1), n(), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1)))) %>%
ungroup() %>%  
filter(draw == 1)

df_sample %>% count(east_rest, draw)

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   east_rest  draw     n
#       <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1         1     1     8
# 2         2     1    16
```